# jQuery/AJAX HTML injection and Gallery Plugins

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I've been playing around with some jQuery and loading HTML from files, and have run into trouble.  Basically, I want the page to extract a URL parameter, load a file that corresponds to `data.html` where data is the parameter value of `gallery` and then inject the HTML stored inside `data.html` into the div `slider`, and then have NivoSlider (a Jquery gallery) hook onto that gallery.

Everything is working fine - the parameter is found, the file is loaded, the HTML is changed (according to firebug).  But the gallery just sits there idling, like it believes there is no HTML is being changed.

Here's my Jquery:

```
//With respect to http://www.jquery4u.com/snippets/url-parameters-jquery/
    $.urlParam = function(name){
        var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
            if (!results) { return 0; }
            return results[1] || 0;     
        }
    $(window).load(function() {
        //Attempt to extract the parameter for gallery.
        var album = $.urlParam('gallery');
        var path = album+ ".html";
        //Is this legit?
        if(album != 0){
            //Kick into loading the gallery.
            $("#slider").load(path);
            //Load the gallery?
            $('#slider').nivoSlider({
                effect: 'fade',
                animSpeed:0,
                directionNav: true
            });
        }else{
            path = "a.html"; //Reset path.
            $("#slider").load(path); //Load.
            //Load gallery
            $('#slider').nivoSlider({
                effect: 'fade',
                animSpeed:0,
                directionNav: true
            });

        }       
    });
```

And the HTML files are as simple as:

```
<img src="a/img1.jpg" alt=""/>
<img src="a/img2.jpg" alt=""/>
```

Do I need to refresh the page or something?  I'm doing this all inside a localhost web server, so I know the AJAX requests are working properly, and firebug confirms that the HTML has been injected correctly.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: And you're sure your path to the images is correct in terms of where this script sits on the server, and those iamges are located??

Comment: It's possible that the animSpeed:0 is preventing the transition from happening.  Do you still have this problem if you set it to, say, 500?

Comment: @redneckjedi Changed the animSpeed, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: @kylek yeah, firebug proves that the html is being injected from the file properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you have to wait until ajax request completes before you set up the slider.

```
    $("#slider").load(path, function(){
        //Load the gallery?
        $('#slider').nivoSlider({
            effect: 'fade',
            animSpeed:0,
            directionNav: true
        });
     });
```

Comment: Ah! You're a genius! Thanks so much, fixed it instantly! I've done like two things ever with Ajax, so I'm still noobish with it. Thanks so much!